# Spring Hibernate shows tons of empty sessions

Tags: spring, hibernate, spring-data

I am using Hibernate 5 with Spring API.  Running Java 8 with apache tomcat9.  Mysql 5.x
I access objects using getSession().getCurrentSession(), and only have one spring session per request.  (happy to paste my struts action, but not sure if it would help).

I enabled stat logging, and it displays all the queries, and session statistics at the end.
So I would see a bunch of queries and then this (correct) one session summary:

```
2017-06-17 19:04:56,621 INFO  org.hibernate.engine.internal.StatisticalLoggingSessionEventListener.end - Session Metrics {
    1591683 nanoseconds spent acquiring 9 JDBC connections;
    1073951 nanoseconds spent releasing 8 JDBC connections;
    1173965 nanoseconds spent preparing 10 JDBC statements;
    6098889 nanoseconds spent executing 10 JDBC statements;
    0 nanoseconds spent executing 0 JDBC batches;
    0 nanoseconds spent performing 0 L2C puts;
    0 nanoseconds spent performing 0 L2C hits;
    0 nanoseconds spent performing 0 L2C misses;
    100987632 nanoseconds spent executing 7 flushes (flushing a total of 413 entities and 1445 collections);
    95887194 nanoseconds spent executing 3 partial-flushes (flushing a total of 130 entities and 130 collections)
}
```

However, after this (session is ended), it also shows about 20-40 empty sessions like this:

```
2017-06-17 19:04:56,873 INFO  org.hibernate.engine.internal.StatisticalLoggingSessionEventListener.end - Session Metrics {
    0 nanoseconds spent acquiring 0 JDBC connections;
    0 nanoseconds spent releasing 0 JDBC connections;
    0 nanoseconds spent preparing 0 JDBC statements;
    0 nanoseconds spent executing 0 JDBC statements;
    0 nanoseconds spent executing 0 JDBC batches;
    0 nanoseconds spent performing 0 L2C puts;
    0 nanoseconds spent performing 0 L2C hits;
    0 nanoseconds spent performing 0 L2C misses;
    0 nanoseconds spent executing 0 flushes (flushing a total of 0 entities and 0 collections);
    0 nanoseconds spent executing 0 partial-flushes (flushing a total of 0 entities and 0 collections)
}
```

Does anyone know if this is normal?

Comment: I'm not real familiar with Hibernate, but sessions typically have an expiration time (30 or 60 minutes is a common default). Unless you explicitly expire a session when you're done with it, it will be active until the expiration time passes. AKA this looks normal and you probably don't need to worry about it.

Comment: Thanks! Really appreciate your comment.  This makes me feel better! haha

Comment: Please post the hibernate spring configuration part (sessionFactory and eventual spring filter and transaction manager config)